# Finding cardinality/possible combinations of sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Problems:

> Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.
>
> (a) How many subsets are there of cardinality $4$? ($15$)
>
> (b) How many subsets of cardinality $4$ have $\{2, 3, 5\}$ as a subset? ($\binom{3}{1} = 3$, but why $\binom{3}{1}$?)
>
> (c) How many subsets of cardinality $4$ contain at least one odd number? ($\binom{6}{4} = 15$ but why does each subset contain at least one odd?)
>
> (d) How many subsets of cardinality $4$ contain exactly one even number? ($\binom{3}{1}$, but why is this also $3$?)

I had no idea how to phrase the topic since I don't really understand what this is. I am having a difficult time with discrete mathematics. I understand how to get the answer to (a) by using pascal's triangle, but don't understand how to go about the other questions. I am at a loss right now, and I have an exam coming up quickly. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Do you know the relation between binomial coefficients and Pascal's triangle? Do you know what a binomial coefficient represents, and how to compute it?

Comment: I understand that each coefficient is an element in a row of pascal's triangle. As for the rest I am at a loss of knowledge.

Comment: Definitions you can just look up either in your textbook or on Wikipedia. Just quoting the "Definitions and interpretations" of "Binomial coefficients" on Wikipedia, about the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$: *Another occurrence of this number is in combinatorics, where it gives the number of ways, disregarding order, that k objects can be chosen from among n objects; more formally, the number of k-element subsets (or k-combinations) of an n-element set.*

Comment: Wikipedia also discusses the relation with Pascal's triangle; effectively the numbers in the triangle are exactly the binomial coefficients.

Comment: Then how can I figure out (b). Why isn't it 4 choose 3 since the cardinality is 4 and I wan't to figure out how many subsets have those 3 specific numbers disregarding order?

Comment: For (b), just think how a four-element subset $T$ can contain $\{2, 3, 5\}$. Then clearly $T$ must also contain $2, 3, 5$ right? That leaves only one element of $T$ undecided, for which there are how many remaining elements in $S$?

Comment: I am still a bit confused, am I assuming each subset contains 2,3, and 5 and then selecting the undecided one from S?

Comment: Question (b) indeed asks for subsets $T \subset S$ with $|T| = 4$ and $\{2, 3, 5\} \subset T$. So that leaves one element undecided. As three out of six elements from $S$ are already being used, that leaves $6 - 3$ options for the remaining $1$ element (or $3$ choose $1$).

Comment: And you can also just list them all: $$\{2, 3, 5, 1\}, \quad \{2, 3, 5, 4\}, \quad \{2, 3, 5, 6\}$$

Comment: I see, thanks for listing them. Though I still have problems thinking through the questions since they seem vague. Any way to better improve with thinking through a question?

Comment: It might help to read through some examples in your textbook/lecture notes first, until you feel confident about counting arguments in these kinds of problems, and then try the problems again.

Comment: That's where the textbook lacks, it has few examples. The lecture is just a word for word regurgitation of the textbook. I will continue to research it more. Thanks for the help, still extremely confused, but I hope this question helps someone else.

Comment: You're welcome. And if you want more example exercises to practice on yourself, you can always click the `combinatorics` tag below your question to find many other similar questions, often with step-by-step explanations how to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> How many subsets have cardinality $4$?

Since the set $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ has six elements, a four-element subset that contains the three-element subset $\{2, 3, 5\}$ must contain one element of the subset $\{1, 4, 6\}$.  There are $$\binom{3}{1} = 3$$ ways of choosing one of those three elements.  As TMM stated in the comments, the three resulting subsets are 
$$\{1, 2, 3, 5\}, \{2, 3, 4, 5\}, \{2, 3, 5, 6\}$$

> How many subsets of cardinality $4$ contain at least one odd number?

Since the set $S$ contains three odd numbers and three even numbers, there can be at most three even numbers in a subset of size $4$.  Therefore, at least one element in any four-element subset of $S$ must be odd.  Since there are 
$$\binom{6}{4} = 15$$
four-element subsets of $S$, there are $15$ subsets of cardinality $4$ that contain at least one odd number.

> How many subsets of cardinality $4$ contain exactly one even number?

If a subset of cardinality $4$ contains exactly one even number, then it must contain all three odd numbers and one of the three even numbers in set $S$. There are 
$$\binom{3}{1} = 3$$
ways of choosing one of the three even numbers in set $S$ to be the only even number in the subset of cardinality $4$.  The three subsets that contain exactly one even number are 
$$\{1, 2, 3, 5\}, \{1, 3, 4, 5\}, \{1, 3, 5, 6\}$$